# Fuzzy Fonts in Vim-Like (Webkit) browsers

Tags: fonts, browser, web, fontconfig

I tried several vim-like browsers such as *uzbl*, *vimb* and *dwb* recently.

All they have in common is the **Fuzzy fonts** rendering in some pages such as **stackexchang** or **github**.

[image]

I've searched and found out the problem is cause by a bitmap font named *Clean*. I added this to my `~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf` but I had no luck.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
    <fontconfig>
        <selectfont>
        <rejectfont>
            <pattern>
            <patelt name="family">
                <string>Clean</string>
            </patelt>
            </pattern>
        </rejectfont>
        </selectfont>

    </fontconfig>
```

Is there a way to fix this problem (preferably without sacrificing all of my bitmap fonts).

Comment: What was the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi, I had the same issue and I basically installed the following fonts:

`ttf-dejavu ttf-droid ttf-droid-monovar ttf-inconsolata ttf-freefont`.

I don't know which distribution you are using but on Archlinux they are all available in the official package repository. You may want to try to install each of them  one by one

Answer (score 0):

Other solution is to remove `xorg-fonts-75dpi` and `xorg-fonts-100dpi` packages. See [this post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1420209#p1420209) for details.