# bloated font size rendered in webkit based browsers

Tags: freebsd, fonts, browser, fontconfig, webkit

Recently after a complete ports update in FreeBSD-10-p7 X86_64, my BSD system is also infected with font problem under webkit browsers such as vimb and dwb or even xombrero.
But the difference is while I have fuzzy rendring problem in webkit under Linux ([1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122669/fuzzy-fonts-in-vim-like-webkit-browsers), [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140333/blurred-75-100-dpi-xorg-font-packages-with-webkit)); under FreeBSD I have fuzzy fonts and bloated font rendering. (see the picture below).

[image]

In any case what is the solution for bloated exploding font rendring in webkit.

Comment: I read so may tips and tricks that I am beyond confused at this point. One of them suggests the Clean font as the source of the problem and the others still insist that the two problems are the same and I should remove `75dpi` and `100dpi` font packages.(which causes the problem inside other X application that are not web related)

Comment: I think at this point some one should shout at webkit developers and ask them when would they solve this problem. right now we are hardly pressed for new engine as webkit failed miserably and opra left his engine for some non-opensource fantasy.